# HTML Form Select nth element

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a select (dropdown) in a form. When I change the value in the drop down I need to find out whether I selected the first element in the drop down or the 2nd element in the drop down?

How can we acheive this using jQuery or JavaScript.

Thanks for your time. I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index()`:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var selectedIndex = $("option:selected", this).index();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ALce/)

Or you can use the plain javascript `selectedIndex` property:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

Personally I'd use the latter as it's better practice (and slightly faster) to use native javaScript constructs where possible, although both will give you the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method for that:

```
var index = $("select option:selected").index();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
var isFirst = $("#myselect").prop("selectedIndex") == "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below jQuery script:

```
$("select").change(function() {
var optionselected = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
alert(optionselected); 
});
```

​​